# How make a rounded view like this

Tags: java, android, view, geometry

How to make a rounded view like this? It is slightly larger than a quarter of a circle

[image]

Here is my code, but not succeed get the same result:
sorry my English, I'm from Brazil

```
public class Circle extends View {
private Context context;

private final Paint paint;
private final RectF rectF;
private final Rect rect;

private int w = 200;
private int h = 200;

private final float roundPx = 100 ;

public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    rect = new Rect(0, 0, w,h);
    rectF = new RectF(rect);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, paint);

        canvas.drawRect(w/2, h/2, w, h, paint);

}}
```

[image]

Comment: Given the specific nature of this shape, your best bet is to create a png of it and just use it as a resource. That looks like it would be a pain to draw. I mean I guess you could use a circle and overlap some rectangles or something but it just seems like more work than it is worth.

Comment: You don't need rectangles at all. Just draw a circle with a radius slightly less than the `View`'s width/height, and its center slightly inside the lower right corner. E.g., assuming your `View` is square: `canvas.drawCircle(.9f * getWidth(), .9f * getHeight(), .9f * getWidth(), paint);`.

Comment: Thank you , that's what I was looking for :)